# When do I query with Searchable and when with Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, lucene, grails-2.0

I user Hibernate as well as the [Grails Searchable Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/searchable) which is based on [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) and [Compass](http://www.compass-project.org/). I was wondering when I should use what for querying objects from the database.

Is there a rule of thumb when to use Hibernate and when to user Searchable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searcable plugin will be highly useful when you think of free form text search through out your application.

To cite an example, if you are working on a banking application and you are building a portal with a search feature. And you want the search to be free form for all the key elements like customer name, ssn, phone number and/or email id, then you would like to index those using searchable and provide the search talking to searchable to get immediate search results. For this to happen you would have to index those key elements at the least. The indices would grow as ans when you add more key search elements.

On the other hand, hibernate will help you provide the detail information if you do not want to index lot of elements. To extend the above example, once you did a search on SSN and you got a hit, on selecting that entry you can use hibernate to fetch the detail information from the underlying persistence layer using hibernate.

**Inference:**
For speedy, high performance, free form search searhable is an option.
For gathering detailed information, post the search, I think hibernate is the way to go unless you want to use searchable for the detail info as well in which case the size of the indices will be in Gigs.

Follow [here](http://smaldini.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/docs/guide/5.%20Searching.html#5.1%20Query%20Strings) in elastic search which might help to understand. 
My point is to make elastic/searchable lighter keeping the heavy lifting part taken care by hibernate.

**NOTE**
On a side note, I would suggest using [elastic](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) instead of searchable. It has also got a groovy API which is useful. Also note that elastic plugin uses v0.20.0 version of [elastic search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) right now, the latest one being v0.90.2 I guess. If required you can directly use elastic search as a dependency and get the latest feature.

Comment: So when you have a class you want to search over whould you do static searchable = true or would you specify only specific properties?

Comment: When I get items = Item.search(query, aruments).results do you mean that I have to reload the objects from the database? Please explain how?

Comment: @confile I would specify particular properties if I am only concerned about those elements to be searchable. If `Customer` has 10 properties in it out of which I only need first and last name, then there is no reason in creating a bulky index for all of them. :)

Comment: Ok so you get: customers = Customer.search(query, aruments).results and now do you reload the results anyhow with hibernate?

Comment: Exactly. Achievement:- indexing is smaller, detailed data got using hibernate is secured, less load on searchable. Plus look at elastic search. @confile

Comment: How do you perform the last step? The reloading of the ojects of the search result? Could you please provide some code for that?

Comment: Follow [here](http://smaldini.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/docs/guide/5.%20Searching.html#5.1%20Query%20Strings) in elastic search which might help to understand. My point is make elastic/searchable lighter keeping the heavy lifting part taken care by hibernate. @confile

Comment: @confile Have not tried that. I have used elastic directly creating my own indices, mappings, analyzers, filters etc with the latest version and not used the plugin directly.

Comment: do you create a separate project or did you integrate it in your app project directly?

Comment: @confile Added it as a dependency to the app. Moreover, I was running elastic server in localhost during dev.